# Unir while con for para rellenar table html de horario laboral

Tags: loops, while

necesito crear un pdf con el registro de la jornada de un profesor. Tengo la tabla Horarios con (id, idProfesor, Dia, HoraIni, HoraFin, Fecharegis)
Siendo el Dia -> 1=Lunes, 2=martes, 3=miercoles...)Este es el código que tengo para generar el pdf, pero sólo muestra 1 día de la semana, el problema es que si el profesor tiene dos días, sólo muestra el día último. 
Como tendría que unir el while con el for para que mostrara los 31 días y rellenara sólamente los días de la semana que tiene el profesor.
Muchas gracias de antemano!!

```
while ($myhorario = $Horaprofe->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $fechacalc=$myhorario['Dia'];
    $fecha=($fechacalc-$primerdia)+1;
    $fecha1 = $fecha + 7;
    $fecha2 = $fecha1 + 7;
    $fecha3 = $fecha2 + 7;
    $fecha4 = $fecha3 + 7;
    if($myhorario['HoraIni'] < '15:00' ){
    $hmi1=$myhorario['HoraIni'];
    $hmf1=$myhorario['HoraFin'];
    }else{
    $hti1=$myhorario['HoraIni'];
    $htf1=$myhorario['HoraFin'];    
    }}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {

if($i==$fecha){
$html.='<tr>
<td width="60">'.$i.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmi1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmf1.'</td>
<td bgcolor="#cccccc" width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="100">'.$hti1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$htf1.'</td>
<td width="140">&nbsp;'.$suma1.'</td>
<td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>';
}elseif($i==$fecha1){
$html.='<tr>
<td width="60">'.$i.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmi1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmf1.'</td>
<td bgcolor="#cccccc" width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="100">'.$hti1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$htf1.'</td>
<td width="140">&nbsp;'.$suma1.'</td>
<td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>';
}elseif($i==$fecha2){
$html.='<tr>
<td width="60">'.$i.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmi1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmf1.'</td>
<td bgcolor="#cccccc" width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="100">'.$hti1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$htf1.'</td>
<td width="140">&nbsp;'.$suma1.'</td>
<td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>';
}elseif($i==$fecha3){
$html.='<tr>
<td width="60">'.$i.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmi1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmf1.'</td>
<td bgcolor="#cccccc" width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="100">'.$hti1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$htf1.'</td>
<td width="140">&nbsp;'.$suma1.'</td>
<td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>';
}elseif($i==$fecha4){
$html.='<tr>
<td width="60">'.$i.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmi1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$hmf1.'</td>
<td bgcolor="#cccccc" width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="100">'.$hti1.'</td>
<td width="100">'.$htf1.'</td>
<td width="140">&nbsp;'.$suma1.'</td>
<td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>';
}else{
$html.='<tr>
<td width="60">'.$i.'</td>
<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
<td bgcolor="#cccccc" width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="140">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Dejo aquí como lo he solucionado por si alguien le puede interesar. Gracias!!

```html
foreach($arr as $row){ 

$horas=$row[2].' a '.$row[3];
$colorprofe=$row[4];

 if($horas<>$ultimo){
   
       $ultimo=$horas;
             echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $horas ."</td>";  
                $ultitd=0; 
                $diaant=1; 
                $sumando=0; 
 }

   
    for($z=$diaant+$sumando; $z<=5; $z++){
           
            if($row[1]>$z) {
            
               /* if ($row[1]<>$diaant){ */
              echo "<td></td>";
      /*  } */
         }
   }      
          
   if($row[1]<>$ultitd){echo "<td>";}   
   echo "<button style='background: #".$colorprofe."' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal'>" . $row[0] . "</button>"; 
   
   $ultitd=$row[1];
   $diaant=$row[1];
   $sumando=1;
  
   

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, es un gran gesto, y una ayuda inmensa el hecho de responder a las preguntas, pero tiene aún más mérito cuando se hace sobre una pregunta propia, teniendo en cuenta que simplemente se podría haber dejado la pregunta en el olvido. Perfecto aporte :)